# Generalizations of de l'Hospital rule

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, reference-request, soft-question, big-list

Are there any useful generalizations of *de l'Hospital rule*? Could you point out some references?

Edit: Something in the spirit of http://arxiv.org/abs/1403.3006, but not necessarily for functions of more that one variable.

Comment: Taylor theorem.

Comment: @Pp.. This is not the shortest comment I saw here but it is very good !

Comment: @Pp.. Apart from that. I meant something in the spirit of http://arxiv.org/abs/1403.3006, but not necessarily for functions of more that one variable.

Comment: I thought it was "L'Hôpital's rule," not "de L'Hospital's rule."

Comment: @columbus8myhw see [page about de l'Hospital](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guillaume_de_l%27H%C3%B4pital) for reference, also have a look at its footnote 1.

Answer (score 0):

Here are a couple of references for certain generalisations:

- L'Hopital's rule for evaluating the limits of complex matrix functions (mapping a matrix to another matrix)

http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1110256X13000096

- L'Hopital's rule for monotonicity (then used for bounding inequalities of differentiable functions)

http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0893965908001456

- This document covers various plausible extensions such as discrete analogues (called the Stolz-Cesaro theorem) and summations

http://condor.depaul.edu/mash/LHospitalmmf.pdf

I hope that helps!